# How do you supply credentials for a gem when deploying Ruby-on-Rails on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Creating an AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment for a Ruby-on-Rails application fails as credentials are required for a particular gem.  Where can I tell ElasticBeanstalk to run bundle config ... username:password during the creation of the environment?

> [Instance: i-0eb20dd6fc7fe1165] Command failed on instance. Return code: 17 Output: (TRUNCATED)...ndle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`. Authentication is required for gems.rapidrailsthemes.com. Please supply credentials for this source. You can do this by running: bundle config gems.rapidrailsthemes.com username:password. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Comment: I think you need to run `bundle config gems.rapidrailsthemes.com username:password` on EB CLI. Probably there is some downloadable CLI for ElasticBeanstalk? (Not familiair with the solution, but Heriku offers something similar)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the equivalent for doing this with EB CLI as you do with docker-compose, just didn't see that mentioned anywhere in the more general documentation.  Thank you for the pointer.  I'll find out what I can.